# How to determine what CloudFormation stack an AWS resource belongs to using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have an EC2 instance and I want to know which cloud formation stack it belongs to **using AWS CLI**.

To do this using boto in python, refer [How to determine what CloudFormation stack an AWS resource belongs to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644127/how-to-determine-what-cloudformation-stack-an-aws-resource-belongs-to)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644127/how-to-determine-what-cloudformation-stack-an-aws-resource-belongs-to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --physical-resource-id i-xxxxxxxxxx
```

Replace i-xxxxxxxxxx by your instance-id or any other physical resource id in general.

> **--physical-resource-id (string):** 
>   The name or unique identifier that corresponds to a physical instance ID of a resource supported by AWS CloudFormation.
>   For example, for an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instance, PhysicalResourceId corresponds to the InstanceId . You can pass the EC2 InstanceId to DescribeStackResources to find which stack the instance belongs to and what other resources are part of the stack. 
>   **Required**: Conditional. If you do not specify PhysicalResourceId , you must specify StackName .
>   **Default**: There is no default value.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStackResources.html